# list of buttons on the page. After I get the list I want to check if the button is displayed on the page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I am new to automation testing and I have been trying to figure this out all day. Anyways I want to go the site and get a list of buttons on the page. Than I want to print the list of buttons that are displayed on the page.

```
package com.practice;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Buttons {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\Oderint dum metuant\\eclipse-workspace\\JAR FILES\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-switch-windows/");

        List <WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.tagName("button"));
        for ( int i=0; i<buttons.size();i++){
            WebElement button = buttons.get(i);
            if(button.isEnabled()){
                System.out.println(buttons);
                }         
            }

    }

}
```

This is what I get when I run the code:

[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (fddbb691263a84a531368a18e6d495b3)] -> tag name: button]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (fddbb691263a84a531368a18e6d495b3)] -> tag name: button]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (fddbb691263a84a531368a18e6d495b3)] -> tag name: button]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (fddbb691263a84a531368a18e6d495b3)] -> tag name: button]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (fddbb691263a84a531368a18e6d495b3)] -> tag name: button]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (fddbb691263a84a531368a18e6d495b3)] -> tag name: button]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (fddbb691263a84a531368a18e6d495b3)] -> tag name: button]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (fddbb691263a84a531368a18e6d495b3)] -> tag name: button]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (fddbb691263a84a531368a18e6d495b3)] -> tag name: button]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (fddbb691263a84a531368a18e6d495b3)] -> tag name: button]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (fddbb691263a84a531368a18e6d495b3)] -> tag name: button]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (fddbb691263a84a531368a18e6d495b3)] -> tag name: button]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (fddbb691263a84a531368a18e6d495b3)] -> tag name: button]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (fddbb691263a84a531368a18e6d495b3)] -> tag name: button]

Comment: Try using By.cssSelector Method.

Comment: Wat do you mean by print the list of buttons?  You are currently printing that value that performing a .toString() on a WebElement returns.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically three things

```
Thread.sleep(10000); // you can also use web driver's implicit and explicit wait or wait for page to load. This is just for example
List <WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.tagName("button"));
    for (int i=0; i<buttons.size();i++){
        WebElement button = buttons.get(i);
        try {
            if(button.isDisplayed()){
                System.out.println(button.getText()+" - is displayed");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(button.getText()+" - is present but not displayed");
            }
        } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("Element is not present, hence not displayed as well");
        }
    }
```

1. Use some wait functionality to load the page properly.
2. Use `isDisplayed` method to check visibility of button. `isDisplayed` will throw error when element is not present and visibled. So used try catch block for handling `NoSuchElementException` exception.
3. You are printing `WebElements` object, ie buttons. Use get text method of button and then print it. You can see which button is visible or which is not visible.

Comment: I just ran the code you recommended. But it just repeats the print statements 8 times.

Comment: It means your page has 8 buttons which prints it is disable or enable. That is what you wanted. You got it what you needs to implement.

Comment: Anything that promotes a Thread.sleep() is a bad thing in my mind, especially when there is no reason to add it.  The OP hasn't noted any problems waiting for elements to appear.

Comment: @Ardesco You are right and I appreciate your point but why I mentioned because he/she directly locating elements after driver.get. I also added comments for just for example.

Comment: The comments imply using correct strategies are an alternative and having a Thread.sleep() as the initial suggestion implies it's the best option.  Really implicit waits shouldn't be used either because they have unintended side effects.  Waits are only useful when you know in advance what you want to wait for, anything else is an arbitrary pause "just in case"

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to print the list of button names that are displayed on the page.

Ans. Remove if condition block and change the print statement. Refer below Code:

```
List <WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.tagName("button"));

    for ( int i=0; i<buttons.size();i++)
    {
        WebElement button = buttons.get(i);

        System.out.println(button.getText());//It prints all the buttons name displayed on the page

    }
```

2. If you want to print the list of button names which are enabled on the page.

Ans. Keep the if condition block, just change the print statement. Refer below code:

```
List <WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.tagName("button"));

        for ( int i=0; i<buttons.size();i++)
        {
            WebElement button = buttons.get(i);

            //System.out.println(button.getText());  //It prints all the buttons name displayed on the page

        if(button.isEnabled())
            {
                System.out.println(button.getText()); //It prints all the buttons name which are enabled on the page

            }    
        }
```

Comment: The question is based on visible functionality, not enable.